# Globally apply SetBrowserRequestCredentials

Tags: blazor-webassembly

Is there any way to apply the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Http extension method SetBrowserRequestCredentials(BrowserRequestCredentials.Include) globally rather than having to do it on every individual request?

I'd like to avoid doing this on every call:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri)
     .SetBrowserRequestCredentials(BrowserRequestCredentials.Include);

var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

and simply have something like this:

```
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this to be a simple solution in .NET 6.

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient(Options.DefaultName, client =>
{
    // setup client
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<CredentialsMessageHandler>();
```

with the following middleware:

```
public class CredentialsMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.SetBrowserRequestCredentials(BrowserRequestCredentials.Include);

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the request not being immutable, you can always create an extension method:

```cs
private static Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAuthorisedAsync(this HttpClient client, HttpRequestMessage message)
{
    return client.SendAsync(message.SetBrowserRequestCredentials(BrowserRequestCredentials.Include));
}
```